# Google Analytics - event tracking - prevent multiple button clicking

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, web-analytics, double-submit-prevention

I have contact button on page. 
Button on click shows contact number. 
Button is linked with Google Analytics goal > event track > on button click > fires script.

If i want to prevent multiple number of clicks (script firing) and have more relevant data from analytics, i wrote the code, that prevenets script firing more than 1 click.

here is the link of website http://www.seoptimizacija.net/#kontakt

here is jquery code

```
var counter = 0;
$("#kontakt-dugme").click(function (){

if (counter < 1){
$(this).val("(+381)61 64 87 420");
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'kontakt', 'klik-na-dugme', 'prikaz']);
counter++;
}
else stop();

});
```

Need opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the Jquery [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event handler

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed
>   at most once per element per event type.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#kontakt-dugme").one('click', function (){
       _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'kontakt', 'klik-na-dugme', 'prikaz']);
    });
});
```